# Flask+d3.js: Passing multiple datasets to html

Tags: javascript, python, json, d3.js

I'm currently learning d3.js for visualization, using Flask as the python backend, and following [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/5987480) of showing two simple charts with different datasets on the same page.

I'm attempting the following modification: instead of using CSVs, I'd like to pass a json file from a python backend (the example just reads in data from two csv files). How might I pass 2 json datasets over? I can pass one as follows:

**Python backend**

```
import flask...

app = flask.Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return flask.render_template("index.html")

@app.route("/data")
def data():
    x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    y = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    js = [{"x":x[i], "y":y[i]} for i in range(len(x))]

    return json.dumps(js)
```

**index.html**

```
<script>
d3.json("/data", function(data) ...)
</script>
```

I've tried writing another python function, like `def data_bar` to return a separate json dataset, but that couldn't be read. In theory, I could pass both data sets in one json dataset, like:

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5]
y = [1,2,3,4,5]
x1 = [10,20,30]
y1 = [40,50,60]
```

But this encounters problems if the domains of the first set (x and y) and the second set (x1 and y1) aren't the same. e.g. the first set could be "student_name" and "grade", the second set could be "class_name" and "average_grade".

Answer (score 0):

render with one data set passed in:

```
return render_template("result.html",resultVarInHtml = myData)
```

render with multiple data set passed in:

```
return render_template("result.html",resultVarInHtml = myData, resultVarInHtml2 = myData2)
```

Now when I load `result.html`

I can use this code to show my data (assuming a key value dictionary object, but you get the point)

results.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
   <body>
   <p>First Data Set</p>
      <table border = 1>
         {% for key, value in resultVarInHtml.iteritems() %}

            <tr>
               <th> {{ key }} </th>
               <td> {{ value }} </td>
            </tr>

         {% endfor %}
      </table>
      <p>2nd Data Set</p>
      <table border = 1>
         {% for key, value in resultVarInHtml2.iteritems() %}

            <tr>
               <th> {{ key }} </th>
               <td> {{ value }} </td>
            </tr>

         {% endfor %}
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

And you will get a proper table, mate.